# Loop and add DropDown item in the Page instead of code-behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wonder if is possible to add DropDown item in the Page instead of Code-behind?

So say I have a DropDown box I want to show year 1900 ~ current year

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server" CssClass="text">
    <% 
        int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        for (int i = 1900; i < currentYear; i++)
        {
    %>
        <asp:ListItem><%=i %></asp:ListItem>
    <%
        }
    %>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Because when I try to do like above it gives me:

> Warning   1   C:\SandBox\MyWebApplication1\MyWebApplication1\Default.aspx:
>   ASP.NET runtime error: Code blocks are not supported in this
>   context.  C:\SandBox\MyWebApplication1\MyWebApplication1\Default.aspx 35  1   MyWebApplication1

Edit: I also tried:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">

</asp:DropDownList>

<% 
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;

    if (currentYear <= 1933)
    {
        currentYear = 2012;
    }
    for (int i = 1933; i < currentYear; i++)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
    }
%>
```

But the DropDownList doesn't have items when display...

=====
Edit: As Splash-X suggested, now it rendered, but all items gone after postback....

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<% 
    int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (currentYear <= 1933)
        {
            currentYear = 2012;
        }
        DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 1933; i < currentYear; i++)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString()));
        }
    }
%>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">

</asp:DropDownList>



    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="MyFunction();"/>
    <div id="MyDiv">
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Doesn't ASP.NET have a Repeater control for this purpose?

Comment: I just checked out Repeater control, but it seem little overkill? I only need to add DropDownItem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an instance where we had a project written in ASP.NET 2.0 and we no longer had the source code to make changes. We needed to modify the states that were being displayed in a dropdown. The old code had US States and Canadian Provinces and we needed to display States only. The dropdown was bound to data source in the code behind so we clear the items and then add all of the items.

```
<%
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    st.Items.Clear();
    st.Items.Add(new ListItem("State", "")); //Add an empty item at the top for default value        
    string usStates = "AA,AE,AK,AL,AP,AR,AS,AZ,CA,CO,CT,DC,DE,FL,FM,GA,GU,HI,IA,ID,IL,IN,KS,KY,LA,MA,MD,ME,MH,MI,MN,MO,MP,MS,MT,NC,ND,NE,NH,NJ,NM,NV,NY,OH,OK,OR,PA,PR,PW,RI,SC,SD,TN,TX,UT,VA,VI,VT,WA,WI,WV,WY";
    foreach (string state in usStates.Split(','))
    {
        st.Items.Add(new ListItem(state, state));
    }
}
%>
<select name="st" class="col" id="st" alt="select" runat="server">
```

The difference is I'm doing my modifications BEFORE the control and the reason I had to do this is any script that comes after the control is changing the dropdown after it is rendered out to the page.

Try moving your code above the  dropdown list. Our code checks to see if there was a post back so we could preserve any value that was previously entered. There is no point reloading the list on every page load, just the first.

Comment: Do you have something in your code that is changing the items in the dropdown? The reason it works is because you've moved the code from after the control (and items) are rendered to before the control (and items) are rendered to the page.

Comment: I did what you said to move the add items scripts before before the control.  But When I click a Button that does the PostBack it gone.

Comment: But if I remove the If(!IsPostBack) and let it to add again every postback and it works....strange.... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't beleive it is. You can have script blocks in the page rather than in the code behind but they would be coded in the same way as the codebehind would be (ie method blocks and referring to the dropdown as an object and calling add methods, etc.) so you are not really gaining anything by doing it in the page.

Comment: I just want to sepereates the UI stuff from code-behide, so the code-behide will contains logic....

Comment: I would argue that what you are doing is logic. Either way though if you really want this sort of stuff separate from other logic then you can either just have different regions in your codebehind class or use partial classes to have two different files for your code-behind.

Comment: The better approach may be to create your own custom user control that is a dropdown list and do all of your logic in it and just use that control. There is no real wrong answer but some answers may make more sense and follow a more structured approach.

Comment: By the way, it's code-behind, not code-behide. Unless you're typing with a cold.

Comment: @Jonners I do have a cold, but I do make awesome typo even I don't lol Thanks, I will correct it.